# Url.Action not creating querystring parameters?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm using the following code but it's not creating any querystring parameters. I've looked as some examples to see what I'm missing but I'm not seeing it.

View

```
<a href="@Url.Action("ExportData","Admin",
        new { contractMonth = Model.ContractMonth,
            requestType = Model.SelectedType })" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">
    <i class="fa fa-download" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
    &nbsp;Export to Excel
</a>
```

HTML that is created

```
<div class="row voffset4">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <a href="/Admin/ExportData" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">
                <i class="fa fa-download" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
                &nbsp;Export to Excel
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I need it to create

```
href="/Admin/ExportData?contractMonth=something&requestType=else"
```

Comment: Is your Controller method accepting these parameters?

Comment: Your code itself looks fine. Do you have any non-default routing rules defined as it should work regardless of what parameters are used (and even if the action / controller doesn't exist).

Comment: Your code is fine. The only thing that could possibly cause the query string to be absent is if both `ContractMonth` and `SelectedType` are null. Anonymous type members which are null, are discarded for the purposes of route values and HTML attributes.

Comment: Thanks....they shouldn't be NULL but I'll have to double check that. My controller is accepting those parameters. Routing is all the default.

Comment: Values being NULL looks like it might be the issue. I'll do some more debugging to confirm though.